# NLTK output changes when using the same input on the same machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

The next piece of code returns different output with the same input(self.SynSets)
Why can it be happening? Am I doing something wrong? or is it caused by python?

```
def FilterSynSets(self):
    self.filteredSysNets = {}
    for synset in self.SysNets:
        for subsynset in self.SysNets:
            length = wn.path_similarity(synset,subsynset)
            if not length is None\
                and length !=1\
                and length >0:
                    target = synset.__str__().replace("'","")
                    source =subsynset.__str__().replace("'","")

                    connection="\"{}\"->\"{}\" [label={}]".format(
                        target,
                        source,
                        str(round(length,3)))

                    self.filteredSysNets[connection] = length
    oldLength = len(self.filteredSysNets)
    avarageVal = sum(self.filteredSysNets.values())/len(self.filteredSysNets)
    self.filteredSysNets = {k: v for k,v in self.filteredSysNets.items() if v>=avarageVal}
    newLength = len(self.filteredSysNets)
    prt = newLength/oldLength*100
    print ("avr -{}\n old -{}\n new - {}\n prec={}".format(avarageVal,oldLength,newLength,prt))
    return self
```

Outputs:
http://screencast.com/t/eFMOROfkPXR
http://screencast.com/t/Fdd6ufhA

Comment: The code seems to be deterministic, so I presume that  `self.SysNets` somehow changed between runs.

Comment: Nope. self.Sysnets is always the same on the input.

Comment: BTW, it's synsets not sysnets =)